# how to find “influence” curve

Tags: animation

I am doing an animation with props. The animation is I put down something on the table.
an make a link with props's joint and hand joint.
How to control this very easily?

[image]

Comment: you should look into the addon called Dynamic Parent that will help you to do it easily

Comment: wow! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the addon called [Dynamic Parent](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent) made by Roman Volodin. You just need to activate it, put your playhead where you want in the *Timeline*, then in the 3D view, select the parent object (hand), shift select the child object (props), display the N panel > *Dynamic Parent*, click on the *Create* button, move the playhead in the *Timeline*, move the parent + child wherever you want in the 3D view, and click on *Disable* when the hand is supposed to drop the object. It has automatically created the necessary keyframes and constraints:

[image]